# Launching R process from java

Tags: java, r, process

I am trying to launch an R process from Java and redirect stdin and stdout.

```
processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder().command("/usr/bin/R").redirectErrorStream(
            true);
try {
        Process p = processBuilder.start();
        OutputStream stdin = p.getOutputStream();
        InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(stdout));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null) {
            System.out.println ("Stdout: " + line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am using Java 1.6. When the program runs, I get the following error:

Stdout: Fatal error: you must specify '--save', '--no-save' or '--vanilla'

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is that error from R?  Is the problem using R vs a java programming problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just run R with a redirected stdin without one of those options:

```
R < foo.R 
Fatal error: you must specify '--save', '--no-save' or '--vanilla'
```

Do you want R to save its working data when its finished (--save)? Or not (--no-save)? You might find --vanilla is appropriate for your use.

```
--vanilla
          Combine --no-save, --no-restore, --no-site-file, --no-init-file and --no-environ
```

I don't quite know how you pass arguments to Java ProcessBuilder things, but maybe its just:

```
processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder().command("/usr/bin/R --vanilla").redirectErrorStream(
            true);
```

or maybe it has methods for setting args.

Comment: Spacedman thanks for your answer which did the trick...I was not realizing the the error message was from the R process.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to pass parameters to R while launching it as a child process:

```
public void startR() {
    List<String> commandAndParams = new ArrayList<String>();
    commandAndParams.add("/usr/bin/R");
    commandAndParams.add("--vanilla");
    processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder().command(commandAndParams).redirectErrorStream(
            true);
    try {
        Process p = processBuilder.start();
        OutputStream stdin = p.getOutputStream();
        InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(stdout));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null) {
            System.out.println ("Stdout: " + line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The resulting out output is:

```
Stdout: 
Stdout: R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) -- "Good Sport"
Stdout: Copyright (C) 2013 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Stdout: Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
Stdout: 
Stdout: R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
Stdout: You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Stdout: Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.
Stdout: 
Stdout:   Natural language support but running in an English locale
Stdout: 
Stdout: R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Stdout: Type 'contributors()' for more information and
Stdout: 'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.
Stdout: 
Stdout: Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
Stdout: 'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Stdout: Type 'q()' to quit R.
Stdout:
```